# Can I add more then one jsoup tag in a document.select?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

Here is my code that I am working on trying to join the two codes, but its not working:

```
td span[id]
tr a[title]
  htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect(urll).timeout(10 * 1000).get();      
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urll).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
  htmlDocument.select("td span[id] + tr a[title]");
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right. Please kindly tell me what am doing wrong, as I have tried many ways, and also looked up in google but no solution was found.

Here is html code I am trying to extract all these info:

```
</td>
    <td><a id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lnkTitle" title="" href="http://demourl.uk/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19279943&amp;JobTitle=Factory%20%2f%20Production%20Operatives&amp;rad=20&amp;rad_units=miles&amp;pp=25&amp;sort=rv.dt.di&amp;vw=b&amp;re=134&amp;setype=2&amp;tjt=factory&amp;where=oldham&amp;pg=1&amp;AVSDM=2015-09-09T09%3a41%3a00-05%3a00">Factory / Production Operatives</a></td>
    <td><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblCompany">TipTopJob</span></td>
    <td>
    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblArea">NW-ashton / under / lyne</span>
    <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblCity"></span>
</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: use http://try.jsoup.org/ to verify your select query

Comment: i have but they are not joining together

Comment: without knowing the source html it's hard to figure out your requirement

Comment: please check html code added to post am trying to extract all them data in 1 string rather then new line